# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'type' and 'float'

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to teach myself python and have run into an error I am not sure of. the error looks like this:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1426, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/home/pi/python/SolutionMixerGUI.py", line 39, in calculate
    fgTotal = self.vol * fgML
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'type' and 'float'
```

I know the error is telling me I can not multiply these two types, I am confused what 'type' is. Can anyone help me clear this error. Full code below.

```
from tkinter import *

class App:
    def __init__(self,master):
        frame = Frame(master)
        frame.pack()
        Label(frame, text='Solution in liters:').grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.vol = DoubleVar
        Entry(frame, textvariable=self.vol).grid(row=0, column=1)
        Label(frame, text='Growth Stage (1-5):').grid(row=1, column=0)
        self.stage = IntVar
        Entry(frame, textvariable=self.stage).grid(row=1, column=1)
        self.fgTotal = DoubleVar
        self.fmTotal = DoubleVar
        self.fbTotal = DoubleVar
        Label(frame, textvariable=self.fgTotal).grid(row=2, column=0)
        Label(frame, textvariable=self.fmTotal).grid(row=2, column=2)
        Label(frame, textvariable=self.fbTotal).grid(row=2, column=3)
        button = Button(frame, text='Calculate', command=self.calculate)
        button.grid(row=3, column=1, sticky=(W, E))

    def calculate(self):
        if self.stage == 1:
             #Seedlings
            fgML,fmML,fbML = 0.33,0.33,0.33
        elif self.stage == 2:
            #Mild Veg
            fgML,fmML,fbML = 1.32,1.32,1.32
        elif self.stage == 3:
            #Aggresive Veg
            fgML,fmML,fbML = 3.96,2.64,1.32
        elif self.stage == 4:
            #Tranistion to Bloom
            fgML,fmML,fbML = 2.64,2.64,2.64
        else:
            #Blooming and Ripening
            fgML,fmML,fbML = 1.32,2.64,3.96
        fgTotal = self.vol * fgML
        fmTotal = self.vol * fmML
        fbTotal = self.vol * fbML


root = Tk()
root.wm_title('Solution Mixer')
app = App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 6):

You forgot to call the constructors.

```
    self.vol = DoubleVar()
```

Answer (score 1):

`self.vol = DoubleVar` should be `self.vol = DoubleVar()`

And also for

```
self.stage = IntVar() 
self.fgTotal = DoubleVar()
self.fmTotal = DoubleVar()
self.fbTotal = DoubleVar()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I added the parenthesis to all assignments. Now the error says:
    TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'DoubleVar' and 'float'


I tried assigning fmML, fgML and fbML as DoubleVar but the same error pops up.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the .get() function when getting a variable assigned as a DoubleVar.

e.g

```
var1 = DoubleVar()
def function():
    var2 = var1.get()
```

(;